# How to send 'Origin' header in Feign Client

Tags: http-headers, spring-cloud-feign

I am quite new in Spring Cloud Feign and trying to send HTTP header which is required by service provider. Here is the code snippet

```
@FeignClient(name = "authentication", url = "http://localhost:3000/api")
public interface AuthenticationService {
    @PostMapping(value = "/login")
    JsonNode login(@RequestHeader("Origin") String origin, @RequestBody LoginParams parameters);
}
```

When I try to send `Origin` header then server does not receive this header. But other headers like `referer` or `x-access-token` are received at server successfully.

I have also tried using `RequestInterceptor` and was not successful to send `Origin` as header.

```
@Component
public class HeaderInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        requestTemplate.removeHeader("origin");
        requestTemplate.header("origin", "http://amjad.localhost:3000/");
    }
}
```

Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with OpenFeign. "Origin" header was blocked by defult, because it was using old Java http client.

After change to OkHttp Client, "Origin" was sent.